# Choose different host part during IPv6 auto configuration

Tags: linux, ipv6

My Internet provider assigns dynamic IPv6 prefixes, which changes every few days.

Is it possible to change the host part during auto configuration, e.g. using the prefix from the router advertisement, but use a postfix, that is not automatically generated from the MAC?

The privacy extension doesn't help in the case, as the addresses are assigned randomly by default and are only short lived.

Comment: dynamic ipv6 ? ugh !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that opaque interface identifiers as by RFC 7217 are not yet implemented for whatever you use.  If you ca do a bit of programming then you can do this by (1) disabling autoconf and (2) intercepting router advertisements, extracting the prefix and creating an address with an interface identifier of your choice.

Privacy exensions: you can change the lifetimes by setting the according parameters.  For linux these are the sysctl variables `net.ipv6.conf.<nic>.temp_prefered_lft` and `net.ipv6.conf.<nic>.temp_valid_lft`.

Comment: That RFC looks really interesting, that would cover my use-case. Hopefully it will come soon, till than I'll use privacy extension addresses with longer livetime. Thanks! :)